# Landscape folder for localized layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

Due to language differences I need to have a separate landscape layout for German. How ever I created a new folder in eclipse to hold the layout but now I`m getting an error. 
Is the name of the folder correct
Heres a link to a screenshot capture

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9OVrUvUh2stdmhkQzNFNkcxS28/edit

Comment: two questions: 1. what is the name of the folder? 2. Can't you just create a separate string and use the same layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support different your app in different language, you can have two options to achieve these.

***A.  Most Preferred way***

You just need to add  `res/values-__/string.xml` different `string.xml`.

To support German language you just need to add `res/values-de/strings.xml` which contain your string values in german which **`Android can display to user at runtime on the basis of their locale.`**

***B. Increases app size as new layout created as per language.***

You need to change the folder name to  `layout-de-land` as per [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: Hi Vikralp can you have a look at the link now.

Comment: @Shauny Had a look at your file. Change your folder from `layout-land-de` to --> `layout-de-land`

Comment: thanks for that, I was pulling my hair out in frustration over it!!

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not work but according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources the name should be `layout-de-land`

> if you use multiple qualifiers for a resource directory, you must add them to the directory name in the order they are listed in the table.

Comment: Hi plaisthos can you have a look at the link now.

Comment: plaisthos thanks for that, I was pulling my hair out in frustration over it!!